# Fast way to initialize a tensor in torch7

Tags: for-loop, matrix, lua, deep-learning, torch

I need to initialize a 3D tensor with an index-dependent function in torch7, i.e.

```
func = function(i,j,k)  --i, j is the index of an element in the tensor
    return i*j*k        --do operations within func which're dependent of i, j
end
```

then I initialize a 3D tensor A like this:

```
for i=1,A:size(1) do
    for j=1,A:size(2) do
        for k=1,A:size(3) do
            A[{i,j,k}] = func(i,j,k)
        end
    end
end
```

But this code runs very slow, and I found it takes up 92% of total running time. Are there any more efficient ways to initialize a 3D tensor in torch7?

Comment: What is the size of  `A`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the documentation for the [`Tensor:apply`](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#applying-a-function-to-a-tensor)

> These functions apply a function to each element of the tensor on
>   which the method is called (self). These methods are much faster than
>   using a for loop in Lua.

The example in the docs initializes a 2D array based on its index i (in memory). Below is an extended example for 3 dimensions and below that one for N-D tensors. Using the apply method is much, *much* faster on my machine:

```
require 'torch'

A = torch.Tensor(100, 100, 1000)
B = torch.Tensor(100, 100, 1000)

function func(i,j,k) 
    return i*j*k    
end

t = os.clock()
for i=1,A:size(1) do
    for j=1,A:size(2) do
        for k=1,A:size(3) do
            A[{i, j, k}] = i * j * k
        end
    end
end
print("Original time:", os.difftime(os.clock(), t))

t = os.clock()
function forindices(A, func)
  local i = 1
  local j = 1
  local k = 0
  local d3 = A:size(3)
  local d2 = A:size(2) 
  return function()
    k = k + 1
    if k > d3 then
      k = 1
      j = j + 1
      if j > d2 then
        j = 1
        i = i + 1
      end
    end
    return func(i, j, k)
  end
end

B:apply(forindices(A, func))
print("Apply method:", os.difftime(os.clock(), t))
```

---

**EDIT**

This will work for any Tensor object:

```
function tabulate(A, f)
  local idx = {}
  local ndims = A:dim()
  local dim = A:size()
  idx[ndims] = 0
  for i=1, (ndims - 1) do
    idx[i] = 1
  end
  return A:apply(function()
    for i=ndims, 0, -1 do
      idx[i] = idx[i] + 1
      if idx[i] <= dim[i] then
        break
      end
      idx[i] = 1
    end
    return f(unpack(idx))
  end)
end

-- usage for 3D case.
tabulate(A, function(i, j, k) return i * j * k end)
```

Comment: you're welcome! (comment removed since it is no more relevant after this [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30560653/5))

Comment: great answer! as long as the functor can get properly JIT-compiled, it'll be very fast (close to C speeds)

Comment: Thank you very much @rpattiso. This is exactly what I am looking for, although I spent some time figuring out how forindices() works. It really helps. By the way, how do you think up this function? Do you read the C source code of Torch7?

Comment: @MarsPlus I'm glad it helped! I read the docs and saw how they initialized a tensor to a sequence using a global variable `i` and incrementing it in the function passed to apply. Then I extended that to 3d my mimicking the loops.